# software-based dual-monitor solution via LAN

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

Does anyone know of a software-solution which makes it possible to use a monitor attached to another (running) PC via LAN in the same way as a second monitor?

My situation is this: I have a PC and a notebook. Sometimes it would be very convenient if I could use the PC's monitor as a second monitor from the notebook. I know that I can attach the monitor to the notebook, but I was thinking maybe there are is a software-based solution, e.g. a program (similar to remote desktop) which would run on the PC and notebook and which would allow me to use the PC's monitor from the notebook as if it were physically attached.

Update: I'm using windows 7.

Comment: I too have used Synergy as a solution (mentioned by osij2is), it works great. Just make sure you read the instructions carefully, it can be confusing to configure it if you don't understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're running Windows, [**MaxiVista**](http://www.maxivista.com/) can do this:

> MaxiVista turns any spare Desktop,
>   Laptop or Netbook PC into a dual
>   monitor for your primary computer. No
>   extra multi monitor hardware is
>   required. Simply extend program
>   windows across multiple screens as if
>   it were one big monitor. Increase your
>   productivity by using multiple
>   monitors.

MaxiVista is not free though.

There is also [**ZoneScreen**](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm) but I've never used it and don't know how well it works.

**Edit**: Actually this question is a duplicate of many questions, as you can see by checking [all questions whose answers mention MaxiVista](https://superuser.com/search?q=maxivista) :-) .

Answer (score 2):

[Spacedesk](https://spacedesk.net) is exactly doing what you want!

Comment: using this one already, it is very good. Thank you

Comment: This should be top answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something like Synergy ([link](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/)), but from their own website:

> Synergy lets you easily share a single
>   mouse and keyboard between multiple
>   computers with different operating
>   systems, each with its own display,
>   without special hardware. It's
>   intended for users with multiple
>   computers on their desk since each
>   system uses its own monitor(s).

I've used it on Windows 2003, Ubuntu Linux and Mac OSX all at the same time. It's a little tricky to setup, but once you get it working, it works flawlessly. Now, for Windows 7, I'm not sure if they've updated it to work with Windows 7, but it wouldn't surprise me if support came soon.

**Edit:** BTW, Synergy is free. :)

Comment: This is not what Martin asked for. He wants the output on 1 single computer on 2 screens, each screen connected to a different computer.

With Synergy, each screen still displays the output of its attached computer, the software switching only the mouse and keyboard.

Comment: I did not interpret his question as you did. Neither did Admin Alive. Thanks for the down vote. A simple explanation would've sufficed.

Comment: Snark is correct, this is not what I was looking for. But still interesting.

Comment: BTW: please feel free to edit/clarify my question if it's unclear (english is not my native language)

Comment: Even though synergy is not what the OP wants, you may also be interested in Synergy+

Answer (score 0):

For Windows only, there also [Extramon](http://www.extramon.com/). There's a trial available but you need to purchase a license after trial.

> Extramon lets you use a second computer as a second monitor, giving you a dual-monitor computer. In fact, both of your computers become dual-monitor computers. And you can operate them both from a single keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Windows 10 - this is now built in, no additional software to install. You can use a second PC as an extended monitor with Windows 10 wireless displays. Good explanation from Scott Hanselman [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/use-a-second-laptop-as-an-extended-monitor-with-windows-10-wireless-displays).

Answer (score -1):

[ShareMouse](http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/index.html) is a good one that is free for personal use and available for Mac and Windows.