# combine two displays of two separate machines

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I have two desktops each with single vga monitor output. I am interested to have an extended monitor setup, where i can extend the desktop of one of my machines and that way i can also work on the other using remote desktop. Any idea how can i do that? I am running Windows 7 on one and Win Server 2k8 on another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for a solution like **MaxiVista**, as already explained [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/68431/software-based-dual-monitor-solution-via-lan/68432#68432) (and in tons of other discussions on SU). Synergy is something else, where each computer keeps its screen, only the mouse and keyboard are redirected.

However, I think it's a bit strange to extend the desktop on the screen of the other computer, and do a RDP connection to access it? But it should work, as the RDP connection will access another session and the Maxivista extended screen will use the interactive session.

[image: Small home-made graphic, just to see if I understood correctly :-)]

Answer (score 4):

Not quite sure how exactly you imagine this to work or look like. I can't quite make sense of it, but that may be the time of day here.

You might want to take a look at [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

As Johannes Rössel writes, [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) is the undoubtedly cheapest and perhaps even the best solution to this problem. It's cross platform (Windwos, OS X and Linux), open source and (after a bit of configuration) completely invisible and easy to use.

Comment: Synergy seems not be be opensource nor free anymore !

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/).

> Synergy is Free and Open Source Software that lets you easily share
>   your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers, where each
>   computer has its own display. No special hardware is required, all you
>   need is a local area network. Synergy is supported on Windows, Mac OS
>   X and Linux. Redirecting the mouse and keyboard is as simple as moving
>   the mouse off the edge of your screen.

[image: Synergy]

Comment: Synergy seems not be be opensource nor free anymore !

Answer (score -2):

what you are asking cannot be done with (2) separate computers. You would need 1 computer with a dual monitor output video card to run extended monitor support. You can though use 2 monitors next to each other and have a KVM switch so you click back and forth between computer towers.

I recommend the dual video output solution, as I am using the same solution. I run 1 tower and dual monitors. Good luck with your setup, if you have any more questions please do ask!

Comment: hi, i am already using the kvm switch to switch back and forth. I had heard there's a software which once installed on both machines can do that where i can achieve extended monitor support without having the split vga hardware.

Comment: Synergy the software that was listed below will allow that without hardware.