# Can I project multiple PC's on one monitor in custom layout?

Tags: resolution, kvm-switch, multiple-desktop

I know there are monitors that can show multiple desktops at the same time. As far as I have seen these monitors alway show the video inputs in a 2x2 layout or [devide the width of the monitor by 2 to show 2 desktops simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/72045/combine-two-displays-of-two-separate-machines).

What I am looking for is a way to show my two PC's in the layout shown below:
[image]

Are there monitors of KVM's (I expect it to be a KVM thing) available that will let me create my own layout on the monitor?

I'm only interested in the video part as one PC does not need any mouse or keyboard input.

---

EDIT:

I do not want the user to be able to modify the layout or have a visible control bar around my smaller pane.

A possible solution (thank you HighTechGeek) is to use an RDP session. This will however enable the user to modify the layout.

A way around this is to control a RDP session through code. This way the borders can be removed and only the desired functionalities can be enabled for the user.

Comment: look for Dual-Channel VGA ?DVI? PIP Video Mixer

Comment: you can also use some software like VNC (TighVNC, UltraVNC or other...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special hardware to do this. Simply use Window's built-in Remote Desktop Connection from PC 1 to remote into PC 2 and size the remote window according to your diagram.

Here's an example I just did using 2 PCs:

[image]

Comment: Although this is the layout I was looking for, I don't want the user to be able to move/close the RDP session. It is my bad for not stating this in my original question.