# How to share a KVM with a PC & two monitors

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I'm trying to figure this out.

Current setup:
KVM switch on my bench where I have several PC's at a time on one monitor.

At my desk I have my PC I use as my workstation with dual monitors.

I'd like a non-software solution for getting the KVM's monitor in a window on my workstation PC.
I currently have a Logitech Master mouse and a switching keyboard so they are able to switch between my workstation and the kvm with a push of a button.

My ultimate goal is to be able to screen record or screen capture on my workstation pictures/videos of the KVM attached display.

a software solution won't work (at least on the client side) because i'm configuring those PC's, and I need to capture video from POST.

Comment: For clarification:https://superuser.com/questions/1148163/can-i-project-multiple-pcs-on-one-monitor-in-custom-layout?rq=1

Comment: Then you need a video capture card.

Comment: I found that VNC viewer plus may solve my issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

try doing that with the phone instead.
then upload it on the PC.
All phones do provide this function , you can use [free minecraft accounts 2019](https://freeaccount.org/free-minecraft-account/) also !
Regards