# Emulate fake monitor on Windows 7?

Tags: multiple-monitors, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

Is there a way to emulate a monitor on Windows 7?

I have one physical monitor, and I want Windows to think I have two. I actually don't care whether the second monitor is visible anywhere, or if I can see it - everything rendered there may as well go to the equivalent of [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) - but I need Windows to think there is one there.

The reason is that I want to run a virtual machine with two monitors with [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) in seamless mode, and it doesn't let me go to seamless mode if there are more virtual monitors than physical ones. I don't need to see the second virtual monitor, but VirtualBox won't just stop displaying it like it did in earlier versions.

I need a software solution to this - a device driver that acts like a monitor to Windows without having a monitor plugged in. This is because I have no more physical plugs available in my video card.

Comment: you may want to edit your question to specify that you want a software solution; a device-driver that appears to Windows as a monitor.

Comment: Related: [software-based dual-monitor solution via LAN](http://superuser.com/questions/68431/software-based-dual-monitor-solution-via-lan)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to fake a dual (second) monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The free product [ZoneScreen](http://www.zoneos.com/zonescreen.htm) may work for you:

> ZoneScreen is a tool for extending
>   your desktop workspace using displays
>   of network connected computers or
>   portable devices like Pocket PC.
>
> ZoneScreen consists of two parts:
>   **kernel-mode ZoneScreen Virtual Display Driver which is visible to Windows just as normal video card** with monitor
>   attached to it, and user-mode
>   ZoneScreen Wizard which is responsible
>   for capturing image (running at server
>   side), transmitting it over the
>   network, and drawing it at another
>   computer (running at client side).

There is also a similar but commercial product: [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/) (US$39.95, trial available).

Comment: basically. how did the bounty get automatically assigned? it didnt go to the highest-voted question it seems

Comment: Highest-voted and answered during the bounty period gets 50% of bounty. Other 50% is wasted.

Answer (score 14):

You can create a [dummy plug (in just 30 seconds)](http://www.overclock.net/folding-home-guides-tutorials/384733-30-second-dummy-plug.html) and Windows will think it is a monitor.

This is not applicable with digital only cards (no VGA or DVI-I)

Comment: hehe cute, but the problem is that i'm out of plugs. i want a monitor without any hardware required

Comment: @Claudiu a new plug is only like a dollar on eBay.  This is the standard way of faking a monitor in Windows for virtual machines.

Comment: @typoknig: er sorry, i meant that i'm out of plug space on the video card. otherwise i could hook up a random monitor as i have a bunch lying around...

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was going to say, it only works if there is an output available to plug it into. Claudiu is looking for a *software* solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are programs to create a 2nd monitor on other devices, such as another computer, or an iPad:

http://www.ngineer.net/technology/using-my-ipad-as-a-second-monitor-for-my-windows-laptop/

If you have an iPad, fine. Or, you should be able to connect to the VNC server from the local host via a VNC client. (connect to localhost:5902) Now the "second monitor" would be in a window on the local machine you can close or display as needed.

Comment: hmm intriguing... i will have to look into this, thank you.

Comment: This does not create a second video device.  It only works if you actually have a graphics card rendering video on that second device.

Answer (score -2):

For Windows only, there also [Extramon](http://www.extramon.com/). There's a trial available but you need to purchase a license after trial.

> Extramon lets you use a second computer as a second monitor, giving you a dual-monitor computer. In fact, both of your computers become dual-monitor computers. And you can operate them both from a single keyboard and mouse.

Comment: "...everything rendered there may as well go to the equivalent of /dev/null..."  Sorry, but the OP wanted a *virtual* monitor. The OP wanted the computer to *think* there was another monitor attached.