# Change the resolution with no monitor connected

Tags: display, resolution

I want to connect to my computer via Teamviewer but the resolution is fixed to 640x480. Im using a RX480 graphics card with current drivers but no monitor.

I browsed through all the threads i could find and tried whatever i could find:

Change in the normal resolution settings is greyed out. [image: control panel]

The list in advanced settings only shows small resolutions [image: advanced]

Raddeon settings disable the options with no monitor connected [image: Radeon settings]

Editing the registry values for Xresolution and Yresolution did nothing

A dummy plug is not a valid option since im 400 km away from it

Comment: Your best place is to ask TeamViewer directly, but looks like lots of TV users are facing similar issue - https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/TeamViewer-12/Can-t-change-resolution-on-client/td-p/1619/page/2

Comment: @Darius while i have seen people having problems with teamviewer, at least for now, thatss not part of my problem since i cant get change the resolution of the computer itself which has nothing to do with teamviewer

Comment: As to my experience - any remote desktop solution (MS RDP or TeamViewer) - you can't change resolution unless something is connected to it. It will default to the lowest resolution. I don't know why that is the case, but that has been my experience.

Comment: Check this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/239420/emulate-fake-monitor-on-windows-7/239421#239421) and also try [this](http://www.overclock.net/t/384733/the-30-second-dummy-plug) dummy connector. This will make your machine assume monitor is connected, then you resolution problem will be solved.

Comment: as stated im way to far away to be able to connect a dummy connector